# React app: Why doesn't app find JSON file?

Tags: reactjs, path

I have a JSON file residing in my public folder, and I have the following code in my app.js file:

`const url = "./nfl2021.json"`

This works fine, but I wanted to move my JSON file into the same folder as app.js (in the src folder).  When I do that, I can't get my app to find my JSON file.  I've tried several different things for the path, but nothing works.  What should it be?

Comment: Code should certainly be able to locate the file in the local file/directory structure. Can you share the file/directory structure and also the file you are attempting to import the JSON file into? Can you also describe how you are building your project?

Comment: You may need to define a loader like { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }

Comment: check your import paths! and/or share them here. `./nfl2021.json` will import from the same folder, `../nfl2021.json` will be the parent folder, `../folder/nfl2021.json` will be a sibling folder...

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I think my problem is really something else because  I see the following error in the console: `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`.  I think I'll just leave my JSON file in the public folder because everything works fine from there.

Comment: are you using create-react-app? if so make sure to read their info on [using the public folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)

Comment: @benmneb I'll take a look.  Lots to learn.  Thanks.